# SQL Server 2008 Auditing - How to tamper proof the logs?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

From SQL Server 2008 Online reference, their suggestion is to save the logs in NTFS Encrypted Folder with proper ACL or Windows Security log. Is there a better option for tamper proofing SQL Audit logs?

Comment: What exact threat you are trying to protect from? You staff? You customer? or anybody entirely. Please be more exact.

Comment: Part of HIPAA compliance, I'd like to audit insider (people from operations) access to Medical data.

Answer (score 0):

Going to the next level. There are tools that create triggers on the key tables in the database, and capture the various accesses performed (read, insert, update, delete, ...) When these triggers fire because of the access, they write the user, users PC, d/t, and data accessed to a separate table / database / server that is protected. This table can be protected in a lot of different ways starting at the file / folder / share / server / SQL Instance / DB permissions levels.

Comment: This looks more like a comment on the question rather than an answer.  Please post it as such when you can.